# Site not secure, while SSL certificate is installed. Site only secure on Wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, security, ssl, dashboard, wp-admin

I am using a Wordpress site with an installed SSL certificate. When accessing the site, it shows that the connection is "Not secure". When clicking on the "Not secure" tab, it shows that the certificate is installed but no further information. Only when accessing the Wordpress wp-admin dashboard, it shows that the connection is secure.

Why does it not show that the connection is secure when accessing the main website? What do I need to do to show that the connection is secure?

Answer (score 1):

The connection is not secure because that pages include images that are not secure. To fix that, you can use the [Better Search Replace](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin to replace the 'http' by 'https' in the image links. After doing that, restart apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`) or your web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of mixed content error just try adding really simple SSL plugin and in the setting there will be a option for mixed content so just turn it on

Hope this works